# How can I make my timer end after 10 minutes from when I click on the screen?

Tags: java, swing, timer, timertask

Currently my timer ends after 10 minutes from when the program starts. I want it to end after 10 minutes from when the user clicks the begin button. I know it's because I have the start set to System.currentTimeMillis(), but I'm not sure what else to set it to. I've been stuck on this for so long. I'm pretty new to Java, so I would appreciate as much specificity and layman language as possible. Thanks for your help.

I don't know if I can bold code, but I bolded the relevant parts of the code that need to be changed to make it easier to find (so there's either an asterisk or it's bold for those parts).

And if it helps, I'm trying to create a program that produces a random number of beats for 10 minutes and then displays the final beat count on the screen after 10 minutes.

Timer class:

```
package com.home.timer;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MyTimer extends TimerTask
{
    Timer timer;
    int count = 0;
    public MyTimer()
    {   
    }

    public MyTimer (Timer timer)
    {
        this.timer = timer;
    }

    public void toDo()
    {
        System.out.println (" Count: " + (count++));
    }

    **long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long end = start + 10*1000;**

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        toDo();
        **if (System.currentTimeMillis() > end)//this is condition when you want to stop task
        {
            timer.cancel();
        }**
    }
}
```

Task class:

```
package com.home.timer;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MyScheduler extends JPanel
{

public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static MyFrame d = new MyFrame();
public static MyTimer t = new MyTimer();

public Font large = new Font ("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 30);
public Font small = new Font ("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 18);
public Rectangle mainMenu = new Rectangle (310,290,60,120);
public Rectangle beginButton = new Rectangle (310, 290, 650, 300);
public Rectangle beginNow = new Rectangle (594, 472, 80,40);
public Rectangle beginNow2 = new Rectangle (594,492,80,40); //new variable because beginNow isn't at right location for some reason
public static String appState = "Begin";

Timer timer = new Timer();
Random time = new Random();
int number = 2000+time.nextInt(3000); //setting period to random

MyTimer myTask = new MyTimer (timer);
MySound myBeat = new MySound (timer);

int firstStart = 1000; //timer will start after x ms
int period = number; //task will repeat after this period

public MyScheduler (MyFrame d)
{
d.f.addMouseListener(new MouseListener()
{
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent arg0) //click button to begin task
    {
        Point p = arg0.getPoint();
        if (beginNow2.contains(p)){
            appState = "Start"; //Start = no dialogue box
            timer.schedule(myTask, firstStart, period); //begin count
            timer.schedule(myBeat,firstStart, period); //begin beats
        }
    }
    public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent arg0)
    {   
    }
    public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent arg0)
    {   
    }
    public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent arg0)
    {   
    }
    public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent arg0)
    {   
    }
});
}

public static void atEnd() //if time is over, then appState changes to Result
{
    while(true){
    **if (System.currentTimeMillis() > t.end)//this is condition when you want to stop task
    {
        appState = "Result";
    }**
    }
}

public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
{
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.drawImage(MyFrame.i.BG, 0, 0, MyScheduler.d.width, MyScheduler.d.height, null); //background picture

    if (appState == "Begin") //Begin = dialogue box
    {
        g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(310,290,650,300);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawRect(beginButton.x, beginButton.y, beginButton.width, beginButton.height);
        g.setFont(large);
        g.drawString("Begin", beginButton.x +290, beginButton.y+210);
        g.drawRect(beginNow.x, beginNow.y, beginNow.width, beginNow.height);
    }

    if (appState == "Result") //shows count at end
    {
        g.setFont(large);
        g.setColor (Color.RED);
        g.drawString(myTask.count-1+" beats", 200, 200);
    }

    repaint();
}

public void startApp() //startApp = Start = toStart
{
    appState = "Start";
}
public void beginApp() //beginApp = Begin = toBegin
{
    appState = "Begin";
}
public void resultApp() //resultApp = Result = toResult
{
    appState = "Result";
}

public boolean toBegin()
{
    return (appState.equalsIgnoreCase("Begin")? true:false);
}
public boolean toStart()
{
    return (appState.equalsIgnoreCase("Start")? true:false);
}
public boolean toResult()
{
    return (appState.equalsIgnoreCase("Result")? true:false);
}

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        d.display();
        atEnd();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Here's how it looks like

```
if (beginNow2.contains(p)) { 
    appState = "Start"; 
    myTask = new MyTimer(timer); 
    timer.schedule(myTask, firstStart, period);
    timer.schedule(myBeat,firstStart, period); 
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    long end = start + 10*1000; 
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() > end) { 
        timer.cancel(); appState = "Result";
    } 
}
```

Comment: Use a Swing Timer not a java.util.Timer for Swing timing issues.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'd have to watch a whole other set of tutorials on swing timers to change my code. It would just be hard for me to change it when I'm only beginning to learn Java. There's no way for me to use a java.util timer and have the timer end the way I want it to? And I thought swing timers were outdated or can do less or something? :/ I wanted to turn this into an app later, so I want it to run well. Thanks!

Comment: @papernemesis If you are modifying the UI from timer, then you will violating the single thread rules of Swing which could cause more issues for you.  Take the time to learn the right tools for the right job...

Comment: Doing things wrong just because you don't want to read another tutorial won't fix the issue that you're doing things wrong. For Swing GUI's, you really have little choice, unless you really don't care if your code works well or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long end = start + 10*1000;
```

These fields in `MyTimer` are causing the problem. They'll be initialized the moment you run the `MyTimer` constructor (at the beginning of your program). Easiest solution would be to create new `MyTimer` instance right before you want to start the countdown (after clicking `Begin`). i.e. right before the `schedule()` call:

```
...
myTask = new MyTimer(timer);
timer.schedule(myTask, firstStart, period);
...
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if I did what you were saying, but I tried putting myTask = new MyTimer(timer); before timer.schedule and it didn't make a difference. I also tried getting rid of the timer.cancel() in the timer class and moving it under if(beginNow2.contains(p)) and the timer won't stop at all now.

Comment: Here's what it looks like now:

`if (beginNow2.contains(p))  
{  
appState = "Start";  
   myTask = new MyTimer(timer);  
   timer.schedule(myTask, firstStart, period);  
   timer.schedule(myBeat,firstStart, period);  
   long start = System.currentTimeMillis();  
   long end = start + 10*1000;  
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() > end)  
    {  
     timer.cancel();  
     appState = "Result";  
    }  
  }`

Comment: I got it to work! It wasn't before because I took away the while loop. So thank you :)